# Does OS reclaim memory on application exit in C?

Tags: c, memory-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When you exit a C application, is the malloc-ed memory automatically freed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213627/when-you-exit-a-c-application-is-the-malloc-ed-memory-automatically-freed)

Pretty much the title. Do (modern) OSs automatically reclaim heap-allocated memory on program termination? If so, is freeing the memory a *strict must* or more of a *just-follow-the-damn- standard-you-fool* kinda thing?

What is the worst thing than can happen if I do not explicitly free the memory except that I end up wasting it while the application is in run?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I'm sorry I did not find that question. I'm voting on close myself as well :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an application terminates, all memory will be reclaimed by the OS. The reason people preach memory management techniques is because so long as the app is *running*, any memory it's asked for will remain in its posession (even if it's no longer being used). Unless, of course, you were nice enough to call `free`.

Answer (score 2):

if the app terminates the os will clean up the memory and resources.
if you do not clean up memory with free( ) then heap-allocated memory will be used up as you request more and more. if it continues, the os will start using swap/page file to allocate. it u still continue os will grind down to a halt, or terminate the app with some kind of error

Answer (score 2):

Does OS reclaim memory on application exit in C? `Yes.`

If you don't free memory: your application may run out of memory & crash.

Answer (score 2):

Freeing memory before exiting is optional because the o/s will clean up for you.

Freeing unused memory while running is a good idea; it prevents the application from running out of memory (and having to exit).  The difficulty is often working out which memory is unused.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. But if your program is a long running program, you not only crash your program eventually, but as the time progresses, you will also slowdown the system, assuming you use too much memory.