# Solving a Variable Equation defined by the User

Tags: c, variables, equation, solver

Answers in C, Python, C++ or Javascript would be very much appreciated.
I've read a few books, done all the examples. Now I'd like to write a simple program.
But, I already ran into the following roadblock:

My intention is to take an equation from the user and save it in a variable,
For example:

```
-3*X+4 or pow(2,(sin(cos(x))/5))       >  [In valid C Math syntax]
```

And then calculate the given expression for a certain X-Value.
Something like this:

```
printf("%g", UserFunction(3.2))   // Input 3.2 for X in User's Function and Print Result
```

Any ideas? For the life of me, I can't figure this out. Adding to my frustration, the solution is likely a very simply one. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't you use `-3 * x` instead of `-3x`? You could use `eval`, but that isn't safe if you're expecting arbitrary user input.

Comment: You're right, -3 * X would be the appropriate syntax. Regarding eval, what do you mean by "not safe"?

Comment: `eval("__import__('os').system('rm -Rf /')")` does just what you think it does.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't imagine a User will input "rm -Rf /" when asked for an equation they want to solve. Any chance you could give me an example of its usage? It wouldn't be as simple as eval(scanf("%s"), x=5) right?

Comment: In Python, it's just `eval('x + 2', {'x': 3})`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There isn't a simple way to do this in *C* but I think [muParser](http://muparser.beltoforion.de/) may be useful to you, it is written in *C++* but has *C* binding. [ExprTk](http://www.partow.net/programming/exprtk/index.html) is also an option but looks like it is *C++* only, on the plus side it looks much easier to get interesting results with.

Another option may be the [Expression Evaluation](http://libav.org/avplay.html#Expression-Evaluation) which is part of [Libav](http://libav.org/about.html). It is in *C* and the [eval.h](https://github.com/libav/libav/blob/6fd221e5f8b0dcd33c249e553ea0be87778f2479/libavutil/eval.h) header has some good descriptions of the interface.

Comment: Sadly, as a beginner I have no idea how to use that. Thank you anyways for your answer, Mr. Yaghmour.

Answer (score 0):

In compiled languages like C, C++, or Java there is no easy way to do this--you basically have to rewrite a whole compiler (or use an external library with an interpreter). This is only trivial in "scripting" languages like Python and Javascript, which have a function (often called "eval()") that evaluates expressions at runtime. This function is often dangerous, because it can also do things like call functions with side effects.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Mr. Crocker. It looks like I'm in way over my head. My idea was to write a simple program to approximate an integral from a to b using Simpson's and Trapezoid rule. I would then solve the function for the appropriate x-values determined by the length and n, then multiply the answers by the appropriate coefficients, .... But it all depends on being able to calculate the user's function for a given X. So it seems I will have to use a simpler language. Thanks again.

Comment: Couldn't this be done by implementing a sudo try-catch in C, like described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586003/try-catch-statements-in-c?

Answer (score 0):

Ffmpeg/libav has a nice simple function evaluator you could use.