# C++ Exception - Throw a String

Tags: c++, exception, error-handling

I'm having a small issue with my code. For some reason, when I try to throw a string with the code below, I get an error in Visual Studio.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    
    char input;

    cout << "\n\nWould you like to input? (y/n): ";
    cin >> input;
    input = tolower(input);

    try
    {
        if (input != 'y')
        {
            throw ("exception ! error");
        }
    }
    catch (string e)
    {
        cout << e << endl;
    }
}
```

Error :

[image: error]

Comment: If you want to catch a string, throw a string and not a string literal. Otherwise catch a const char*. Although it would be a better idea to use one of the exception classes.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are currently throwing a `const char*` and not a `std::string`, instead you should be throwing `string("error")`

edit: the error is resolved with

```
throw string("exception ! error");
```

Comment: Yes , but its catching: throw ("exception ! error");  which is a string

Comment: @Jimmy yes, so it's not finding a case for catching a `const char*`

Comment: @SyntacticFructose - This is dangerous (throwing/catching a `std::string` by value), since a string has to be constructed, which may throw an error.  The string should be caught by reference.

Answer (score 24):

**Throwing a string is really a bad idea.**

In your code you are throwing a `const char*`. Throwing a built-in type (like an `int`, or `float`, or a `const char*` like in this case) is a bad idea because these built-in types don't carry proper contextual error information. In fact, when an exception is caught, it's important to understand the *reason* for the exception to take proper action. But a built-in type doesn't properly provide such information, making it difficult at the catch-site to understand the *reason* and the *cause* for the exception.

Moreover, throwing a built-in type is also confusing, as it's not idiomatic modern C++. The idiomatic C++ way of throwing an exception is to define a **proper C++ class** to represent the exception, typically deriving it from `std::exception`, or from some other class derived from `std::exception`, and then `throw` an instance of such exception class.
You could also simply throw some of the C++ exception classes already defined in the C++ Standard Library, like [`std::runtime_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error).

For example, you could throw a `std::runtime_error`, passing an error message string to the constructor, like this:

```
throw std::runtime_error("Your error message");
```

and, at the catch site, you can catch the `runtime_error` exception by const reference (`const &`), and invoke the `what()` method to get the error string.

```
try {
    ...
} catch (const std::runtime_error& ex) {
    // Invoke ex.what() to get the error message
}
```

But do *not* throw the "naked" string.

---

In case you want to define a **custom exception class**, you can derive it for example from `std::runtime_error` like this:

```
class YourCustomException
    : public std::runtime_error 
{
  public:

    YourCustomException(const char* message)
        : std::runtime_error(message) {
    }

    YourCustomException(const std::string& message)
        : std::runtime_error(message) {
    }
};
```

throw it like this:

```
throw YourCustomException("Your error message");
```

and catch it like this:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (const YourCustomException& ex) {
    // Invoke ex.what() to get the error message
}
```

Comment: I agree, throwing anything not related to `std::exception` is a really bad idea…

Comment: Or even just throw a `std::runtime_error('exception text')`.

Comment: Why?  I appreciate the advice, but what's the reasoning?

Comment: @feuGene You may want to have a look at [this C++ FAQ](http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/exceptions#what-to-throw).

Comment: @Mr.C64: That page explains why it's useful to throw derivations of std::runtime_exception, and advises that it's "best to throw objects, not built-ins," but it still doesn't explain what's so bad about throwing built-ins.

Comment: missing some explanation, why it's bad idea etc.

Comment: I added a more elaborated explanation and sample code.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()  
{
    
    char input;

    cout << "\n\nWould you like to input? (y/n): ";
    cin >> input;
    input = tolower(input);

    try
    {
        if (input != 'y')
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Exception ! Error");
        }
    }

    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << "Caught exception: " << e.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).