# How to handle error in C?

Tags: c, error-handling

Say, I have code like this:

```
int foo() {
    ...
    int buff_size;
    scanf("%d", &buff_size);
    FILE * fp = fopen("./file", "a+");
    char *buff = malloc(buff_size*sizeof(char));
    char *buff2 = malloc(buff_size*sizeof(char));
    char *buff3 = malloc(buff_size*sizeof(char));
    while (!feof(fp)) {
        /*do something, say read, write etc.*/
        if (/*error case 1*/) {
            free(buff);
            free(buff1);
            free(buff3);
            fclose(fp);
            return -1;
        }
        else if (/*error case 2*/) {
            free(buff);
            free(buff1);
            free(buff3);
            fclose(fp);
            return -2;
        }
        ...
        else if (/*error case k*/) {
            free(buff);
            free(buff1);
            free(buff3);
            fclose(fp);
            return -k;
        }
    }
    ...
    free(buff);
    free(buff1);
    free(buff2);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
    }
```

for C doesn't provide *try...throw...finally* syntax, I have to close file descriptors and free heap memories pointer that I created before I return a error integer code. It produces some duplicated code that makes the code ugly.

Do anyone know how should I modifly this kind of code to make it looks more brief?

Comment: If you always allocate the same fixed size, why not use arrays? Also please read [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: Why have you tagged this as C++?

Comment: Why not change `char *buff = malloc(1024*sizeof(char));` to `char buff[1024];` (ditto with the others)?

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is _always_ 1.

Comment: `c++` tag should be removed from the question. Coz, answer will different in `c++` than in `c`.

Comment: It just a example. For many case, the buffer's size is determined by the input, so array doesn't works unless I use C99 standard.

Comment: Good discussion of "try catch" in C: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586003/try-catch-statements-in-c

Comment: Never use `while (!feof(fp)) {`   The function: `feof()` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful  2) the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the standard as 1, multiplying by 1 has absolutely no effect and just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest removing that expression.

Comment: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 4):

Your code, as written is equivalent to

```
    FILE * fp = fopen("./file", "a+");
    int return_value = 0;                  /*  assume zero means no error */
    char *buff = malloc(1024*sizeof(char));
    char *buff2 = malloc(1024*sizeof(char));
    char *buff3 = malloc(1024*sizeof(char));

    while (feof(fp))
    {
        /*do something, say read, write etc.*/
        if (/*error case 1*/)
        {
            return_value = -1;
        }
        else if (/*error case 2*/)
        {
            return_value = -2;
        }
        // ...
        else if (/*error case k*/)
        {
            return_value = -k;
        }
    }

    if (return_value == 0)   /* if no error has occurred, we can still do stuff  */
    {
        ...
    }

    /*   I have assumed all buffers need to be released 
         and files closed as the function returns
    */

    free(buff);
    free(buff1);     /*  you probably intend buff2 and buff3 here, to match the malloc() calls */
    free(buff2);
    fclose(fp);
    return return_value;
}
```

I have not, however, addressed two critical errors in your code.  You need to.

- `fopen()` can fail, and return `NULL`.   If it does, passing it to `feof()` or to `fclose()` gives undefined behaviour.   Your code is not checking that at all, and needs to both before call of `feof()` and `fclose()`.
- A loop of the form `while (!feof(fp)) {read_something_from(fp); use_something();}` is a bad idea.   Have a look at [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) for more info.

Less critical - for fixed size arrays (size fixed at compile time) you probably don't need to use `malloc()` which also means you don't need to use `free()`.   However, you still need to deal with potential failures  of `fopen()`.

Comment: Shouldn't the `while`-loop be left in case of any error?

Comment: @alk - I did not suggest avoiding a `while` loop.    I said that `while(!feof())` (specifically) is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

For this sort of thing with common cleanup code, I'd use a return value variable and a `goto`:

```
int foo() {
    ...
    // append extended mode ... what are you doing with this?
    FILE * fp = fopen("./file", "a+");
    char buff[1024];
    char buff2[1024];
    char buff3[1024];

    int ret = 0;

    while (/* file I/O is valid on fp */) {
        /*do something, say read, write etc.*/
        if (/*error case 1*/) {
            ret = -1;
            goto cleanup;
        }
        else if (/*error case 2*/) {
            ret = -2;
            goto cleanup;
        }
        ...
        else if (/*error case k*/) {
            ret = -k;
            goto cleanup;
        }
    }
    ...
cleanup:
    free(buff);
    free(buff2);
    free(buff3);
    fclose(fp);
    return ret;
}
```

This also prevents having to copy-paste code, or retyping with errors (as your current code has).

Comment: Please read the comment above about the use of `feof` in `while` looks

Comment: Edited. Now OP should choose their "is valid" expression.

Comment: using `goto()` is a horrible idea.  the result is 'spaghetti' code.  Much better to write a 'sub' function that handles the cleanup and pass it any parameter values that it needs.