# Enter the value of two number

Tags: c, input, scanf

Actually, I'm learning C langage and I have written a programm

Enter the value of 2 numbers as shown below.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a, b, c;
    printf("Enter two numbers to add\n");
    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
    printf("Sum of the numbers = %d\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

But if I enter an alphabet I'm getting some 1522222 numbers. Instead of 
this I want it throws an error as invalid input if I type alphabet ie a,b,c.

How could I do that?

Comment: Please do some research of your own before asking on SO. A simple google search will help, e.g.: https://study.com/academy/lesson/validating-input-data-in-c-programming.html

Comment: You never add `a` and `b` so what do you expect. You are kind of asking "what's the result of `1 + 1` if we never add the operands together". Very very basic elementary school math.

Answer (score 6):

You can check the return value of [`scanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/). If it is successful, it should return `2`, since you're reading two values. If you get anything else, you know that the input is incorrect. Try this:

```
if (scanf("%d%d", &a, &b) != 2)
    printf("Invalid input type!\n");
else 
    printf("Sum of the numbers = %d\n", a+b);
```

On a different note, you don't initialize `c` anywhere, so printing it is undefined behavior. You don't even need `c` for this, you can just print `a+b` instead.

Comment: Efficient solution, what about this [try-catch in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586003/try-catch-statements-in-c) ?

Comment: There are no exceptions (try/catch) in C. Forget the question you're refering to, it's an advanced usage. Get the basics first

Comment: @SaurabhPBhandari: No, that would be lunacy. This is good answer as it is.

Comment: True, but in a way setjmp and longjmp were made for exceptions to some extent

Comment: @SaurabhPBhandari: No they were not.

Comment: @Bathsheba, I beg to differ [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setjmp.h)

Comment: @SaurabhPBhandari Still, it's nothing OP should even think about in at least a couple of years.