# C how to free malloc'ed memory when program can encounter error and exit at different places?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, free

I'm struggling to come up with a clean way to handle my allocated memory in C. Suppose I have something like this:

```
void function(int arg) {
  char *foo;
  foo = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
  int i = func1(arg, &foo);

  char *bar;
  bar = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
  int j = func2(&bar);

  free(foo);
  free(bar);
}
```

My problem is that `func1` and `func2` may encounter error and `exit(1)`, so I need to free `foo` and `bar` when that happens.

If `func1` encounters error, I just call `free(foo)` and I'll be good. But if `func2` encounters error, I cannot just call `free(bar)` since I also need to free `foo`. This can get really complicated and I feel that this is not the right way to handle memory.

Am I missing anything here? It will be awesome if someone can point me the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: If they are doing `exit(1)` then you don't need to free anything - the system will do that for you when the process is torn down.

Comment: Generally (not in this case) [you need `goto`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10464368/596781) to write systematic C in the presence of resource acquisition.

Comment: @DouglasLeeder so if I don't free when `exit(1)` is that not considered a memory leak?

Comment: @iBlue: generally, no. However, if you're code ever ends up using different means of error recovery, a memory leak could ensue if the then-required changes are not made. (If you declare all your pointers and initialize them to `NULL` before the first `malloc` takes place, your error recovery section can simply call `free` with all of them.)

Comment: Correct. You should not free before exiting. In general, however, having random functions `exit(1)` is not a good idea, as it inhibits code reuse.

Comment: @WillPalmer so what's a better way than `exit(1)`? Should I just return something like -1 to mean error and handle that in main function?

Comment: Using `exit()` in production code might lead to situations comparable to parachuting out of your plane, just because you ran out of petrol. Try to design your system to be able to bring down the plane by normal ways in any possible case.

Comment: @iBlue: it will be *reported* as a type of memory leak by your leak-detection software. So even though it's not harmful in production code, there's some incentive to clean up where possible in order to keep spurious warnings from obscuring any real memory leaks. In practice you care a lot more about another kind of leak: unreachable unfreed blocks while the program is still running are much worse than unfreed blocks at program exit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `func1()` or `func2()` is going to call `exit(1)` on some condition, you don't have worry about freeing memory for `foo` or `bar` as the operating sytem will typically do clean up once the process exits.

As long as you `free` at the right time (before going out of `function`) during the normal course of execution, you are just fine with no memory leak.

Comment: Does that mean when you do `exit(1)` you don't need to worry about memory leak at all and it will be taken care of? (so that when you run valgrind, for example, it won't complain?)

Comment: @iBlue, valgrind on a run that aborts is usually not telling you the right things about leaks anyhow.

Comment: It will probably complain, though no harm is done in modern operating systems. I'd free the memory nevertheless. Can't you change func1 and func2 to return error codes instead of simply exiting?

Comment: That's right. You code as such is quite fine. Because you can't handle the case where `exit` may be called and is also unnecessary.

Comment: @iBlue This is similar to what would happen if the process (your program) is killed directly by OS when it's still running. If you can't avoid calling `exit`, it's ok to leave it as you have now.

Answer (score 3):

If a function calls `exit` you don't have to clean your memory usage at all, it will be freed by the OS. But if you need to release other resources (e.g. lock file, clean temp files, ...) then you can use the [`atexit`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Cleanups-on-Exit) function or if you use the gnu libc the [`on_exit`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Cleanups-on-Exit) function to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I think so there can be a one simple approach to this problem.

Just maintain an allocCode throughout your program when allocating resources something like one given below.
There are few keypoints to remember. First is that, don't you `break` statement in your switch case. Increment the allocCode, for every successful allocation of resource. For every resource added, you should add a case in the switch at the top, with one higher number. So calling the function `freeResourceBeforeExit()` will free all your resources in correct order. Remember that, since there is no break, the switch case will enter at the correct position and free all the resource which are below its entry point.

I will write the psuedo-code.

```
int allocCode = 0;

int freeResourceBeforeExit()
{
    switch(allocCode)
    {
        case 4:
           free(resource3);
        case 3:
           free(resource2);
        case 2:
           free(resource1);
        case 1:
           free(resource0);
    }
    exit(0);
}


int main()
{
   ...
   resource0 = malloc(10);
   allocCode++;
   func1();
   ...
   resource1 = malloc(100);
   allocCode++;
   func2();
   ...
   resource2 = malloc(1000);
   allocCode++;
   ...
   func3();
   ...
   resource3 = malloc(10000);
   allocCode++;
   func4();
   ... 
   so on..
}
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

If you divide your work into several parts, it will be much easier to manage your resources.

```
void part1(int arg) {
  char *foo;
  foo = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
  int i = func1(arg, &foo);

  free(foo);
}

void part2(void) {
  char *bar;
  bar = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
  int j = func2(&bar);

  free(bar);
}

void function(int arg) {
    part1(arg);
    part2();
}
```

Now each part can `free` its parameter before exiting, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

In principle you *could* install a handler with `atexit` that knows how to free your buffers. The handler will be called as a consequence of `func1` calling `exit`. It's not very pleasant to use -- the handler takes no parameters, which means you need to use globals (or local static variables) to store the thing that needs to be freed. It can't be unregistered, which means you need to set those globals to null (or some other special value) to indicate that you've freed the resources yourself, but the handler will still be called. Normally you'd use the `atexit` handler as the "hook" from which to hang your own resource cleanup framework.

In practice, that's usually too much hassle for a few `malloc`ed buffers, because when the program exits a full-featured OS will in any case release all memory reserved by the process.

It can even be costly to free memory before exit - in order to free each allocation with `free`, the memory will be touched, which means it needs to be dragged into cache from main memory or even from swap. For a large number of small allocations that might take a while. When the OS does it for you, it just unmaps the memory map for the process and starts re-using that address space / memory / swap space for other things in future. There are benefits to cleaning up (for example, it makes your code easier to re-use and it makes real leaks easier to find), but also costs.

By the way, it's rather anti-social of the function `func1` to call `exit` on error, because as you've discovered it places limits on users of the function. They can't recover even if they think their program can/should carry on despite `func1` failing. `func1` has in effect declared that it is too important for the program to even dream of continuing without its results. Yes, GMP, I do mean you.

Answer (score -2):

One way of dealing with it:

```
void function() {
  int size = 100;
  char bar[size];
  char foo[size];

  // do stuff

  //compiler frees bar and foo for you
}
```

Comment: The compiler will most definitely, 100%ly **not** call `free` in this code.

Comment: Ok not call `free`, but will `free` the memory, no?

Comment: @KerrekSB so can you please tell me if the memory allocated this way will, or will not be released after the function exits? I'm just curiuos - I always thought it will allocate the space on stack, and release it afterwards.

Comment: In some way yes, after the program exits, the stack will be restored to the previous state, so the memory is effectively free.

Comment: so is it not a way to deal with OP's problem?

Comment: Those variables are automatic, and their memory is managed automatically. It's exactly the same for `size`, and for some reason you were never worried about "freeing `size` for you", were you?

Comment: No I wasn't, and I thought that was the point of the question - a way not to worry about freeing memory. And they are not `automatic`, they are allocated on the stack.

Comment: @wroniasty, it's impossible to say. Perhaps OP would use this solution instead if the functions didn't require dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: @eq ok i see, he did say 'my *allocated* memory'. I stand corrected :)