# dealing with C++/C structures memory freeing

Tags: c++, c

Must I free structure memory after using it? I have sample code:

```
struct aa 
{
int a;
char * b ;
    aa()
    {
    a=0;
    b= new char[255];
    }
} ;


aa *ss = new aa[3];

void fill()
{
    aa * ssss = new aa;
    aa * sss = new aa;

    sss->a=10;
    ss[0] = *sss;
    cout<<ss[0].a<<"\n";
    ss[1] = *sss;

    cout<<ss[1].a<<"\n";
    cout<<ssss[1].a<<"\n";
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{


    fill();
    delete(ss);
}
```

Must I do `delete(ssss)` at the end of `fill`?

Must I delete `ss` array of structure at the end of `main`?

Must I create destruct or to structure ss that frees *b memory?

What about classes is it the same logic?

Comment: I'd say no to everything: use `std::string` for `b`, `std::array` (or `std::vector`) for `ss`, and normal objects for `ssss` and `sss`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Did anyone say it was? Or are you just complaining about the unnecessary parentheses?

Comment: For gawd's sake, give `aa` a destructor.  It allocated its memory; it should be the one to free it.

Comment: @Mike: The end problem is use of `delete` where `delete[]` is required.  The extra parentheses suggest to me that the root cause is someone thinking `delete` is a function.

Comment: Along with the problems others have already noted, there's also the minor detail of undefined behavior. Leaving out some unrelated code, we have: `aa * ssss = new aa;` [ ... ] `cout<<ssss[1].a<<"\n";`. Without the intervening code, the problem is pretty obvious -- `ssss` points to a single `aa` object, but you're trying to treat it as an array of (at least) two.

Comment: @cHao: Bad advice, IMO. Instead of adding a destructor (and, to actually work, probably a copy constructor and assignment operator) just define `aa` as: `struct aa { int a; char b[255]; };`

Comment: @Jerry: Yeah, that works a lot better in this case.  I was initially assuming he allocated the array separately for some reason, but it could easily be that he just didn't know better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Must I do delete(ssss) at the end of fill?

Yes, you must delete anything created with `new`. However, there's no need to use `new` here, just make it automatic:

```
void fill() {
    aa ssss; // automatically destroyed on exit from the function
}
```

> Must I delete ss array of structure at the end of main?

Yes, but it is an array, so must be deleted as an array:

```
delete [] ss;
       ^^
```

But again, there's no reason for this to be dynamically allocated:

```
aa ss[3]; // automatically destroyed on exit from the program
```

> Must I create destruct or to structure ss that frees *b memory?

If you really want to use a raw pointer to manage the dynamic array, then yes. You will also need to think about a copy constructor and copy-assignment operator (per the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4172722/204847)) to make the class safe to use. Alternatively, use a smart pointer or container to manage the memory for you:

```
struct aa 
{
    int a;
    std::vector<char> b ;

    aa() : a(0), b(255) {}
} ;
```

> What about classes is it the same logic?

Yes, the rule is always the same: anything created with `new` must be destroyed with `delete`. Managing objects is much easier if you avoid dynamic allocation where possible, and use smart pointers, containers and other [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) classes when you really do need it.

Answer (score 5):

If you use `new`, you must use `delete` to avoid a memory leak. If you declare a variable on stack, it will be freed automatically when you exit the scope.

```
void something();
{
    aa b = new aa();
    // Do something
    delete b; // You must use delete
}

void something();
{
    aa b();
    // Do something
    // You don't have to use delete
}
```

In your **specific case**, it is not strictly necessary to use `delete`, because the program is going to terminate anyway and all the assigned memory will be freed by the OS.

It is still a good practice to do so, so as to be consistent (though there are some specific cases where you DON'T want to do this because freeing a lot of complex objects can take some time thus slowing down the program termination).

Anyhow, using naked pointers is not such a good idea in C++ since there are many so-called smart pointers (such as `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr`) that take care of calling the destructor and freeing the memory after they run out of scope.

**PS:** In your code, you will have a memory leak, because the `aa` structure uses `new` inside the constructor and does not call `delete` in destructor.

Comment: Using `auto_ptr` is discouraged for good reasons. If using c++11 I would suggest `unique_ptr` instead, otherwise its either `shared_ptr` or boost `unique_ptr`

Comment: Yep, lots of programs love to free every little bit of memory at shutdown. While I can understand the temptation, as a user I personally prefer not having to wait several seconds while it does so..

Comment: ..or forever, if some thread/s is/are stuck.  I cannot understand the temptation to write unnecessary code at all, especially unnecesary code that is difficult, awkward, messy, complex,needs testing on every OS/multicore environment to make sure it still works and adds nothing to the app runtime functionality.  The more code, the more bugs :(

Answer (score 0):

## **YES**

Please, please, please free your memory. I won't go into detail here, but take a look at this answer:
[Can a memory block allocated by using operator new/malloc persist beyond end of program execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383401/can-a-memory-block-allocated-by-using-operator-new-malloc-persist-beyond-end-of/11383451#11383451)

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thumb in `C/C++`:

- Allocated with `new`? free the memory with `delete`
- Allocated with `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc`? free the memory with `free(void*)`